# type object "TimeDistance" has no attribute "time"

Tags: class, oop, attributes, python-3.6

i'm trying to make a time distance calculator in which each object would represent a problem, or "implementation" of the formula, distance = speed * time(that might not be 100% correct, don't quote me.

anyway, the problem is that the compiler keeps throwing an error any time i try to run, saying that "time is not defined". I've made time a global variable within a try catch loop, so a little more clarity on  what I've done wrong here.

the error is within the classmethod speedTime at line 28:

```
#key principle for this program: each object is a question, or instance of the equation d = s * t.
```

import time as t

class TimeDistance:
    def **init**(self, speed, distance, time):
        self.speed = speed
        self.distance = distance = distance
        self.time = time

```
@staticmethod
def gap():
    print("====================================")
    t.sleep(0.5)


@staticmethod
def typeMessage(): #type message that is displayed when the wrong type is entered
    print("value is of wrong type. please enter either a whole or decimal number")
    print(" ")
    t.sleep(0.5)

@classmethod
def speedTime(cls): #get this method working for 6/11/17

    loop = True

    #we need try catch loops:
    while(loop):
        try:
            global speed
            speed = float(input("Enter the velocity in metres per second:"))
            loop = False

        except ValueError:
            TimeDistance.typeMessage()


    while(loop):
        try:
            global time#looks like scope is a problem.
            time = float(input("Enter the time taken in seconds:"))

            loop = False

        except ValueError:
            TimeDistance.typeMessage()



    distance = speed * time

    ob = TimeDistance(speed, distance, time)

    print("The total distance travelled in kilometers is {0} km".format(ob.distance))


@classmethod
def distanceTime(cls): #don't worry about this untill

    distance = float(input("enter the distance travelled in km:"))
    while type(distance) != float:
        TimeDistance.typeMessage()
        distance = float(input())


    speed = float(input("Enter the velocity in metres per second:"))
```

TimeDistance.speedTime()

side-note: is there anything wrong with declaring global variables in the way i did?